# Can I use FingerprintManager instead of BiometricPrompt in API 28 or newer?

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

Can I use [FingerprintManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager) instead of [BiometricPrompt](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/biometrics/BiometricPrompt) in API 28 or newer?

I noticed there is a lot of apps that used AuthenticationCallback but not sure that AuthenticationCallback backs to `FingerprintManager` or `BiometricPrompt` but these apps don't show dialog when using the AuthenticationCallback.

I don't want to use `BiometricPrompt` because I don't want to show any dialog so is it good to use `FingerprintManager` instead of `BiometricPrompt` in API 28 or newer?

Comment: It may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62228113/add-custom-layout-to-biometric-prompt

Answer (score 0):

The same research did by me. I tried to add fingerprint authentication with BiometricPrompt but you know that has shown the UI also.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30328985)